# Are images downloaded when they are hidden?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fancybox

I am using the jQuery plugin `FancyBox` from: http://fancybox.net/ and I'm basically using it for a "hidden gallery"; meaning the images aren't displayed on the page at all, the gallery is launched via a text link and then the user can scan through them once opened.

To achieve this I am doing something like this:

```
<div class="all_images">
    <a href="images/1.png" class="gallery" rel="g1"></a>
    <a href="images/2.png" class="gallery" rel="g1"></a>
    <a href="images/3.png" class="gallery" rel="g1"></a>
</div>
```

Then in CSS I do:

```
.all_images {
    display: none;
}
```

Now I'm wondering if the images are downloaded like this because they are hidden or does it vary by browser?

I'd probably prefer it if they didn't as some images may be large and I don't want the user downloading a bunch of images if they don't wish to view them.

Comment: The dev tools of web browsers have a "Net" tab which tells you which HTTP requests were made. Just open that "Net" tab, and load the page. You will see if images were requested.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Good point - thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example you are not displaying `<img/>` elements.  You only have hyperlinks that will link to the image if clicked.  There will be no downloading.

If they were `<img/>` tags, they would be downloaded even if they were set to `display:none`

Comment: Hahahaha good point. I wrote the code about a month ago, guess I forgot how I did it and didn't take much notice when I came back to it haha

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to optimize the page by removing unnecessary downloads of images. You could combine all of those images in to one big image and load this image as a background-image; You can then leverage the CSS background-position; property to use the piece of image under each item(div, a, li et-al). This way you will be making just one http request to load all the images, which is good page optimization technique and avoiding unnecessary http requests.